# Accept UK date format in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am sending the valid UK date `28/07/2014 10:53:46` to my database to get inserted. However the below statement says `The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`

```
INSERT INTO user_Log (Id,IP,DateTime) 
VALUES (6, '127.0.0.1', '28/07/2014 10:53:46');
```

But if I exchange the data&month part like below it works. What should I make the changes in the database to accept UK date format?

```
INSERT INTO user_Log (Id,IP,DateTime) 
VALUES (6, '127.0.0.1', '07/28/2014 10:53:46');
```

Comment: Where are you sending this query from? If it's from code in some other language, find the appropriate way for you to pass parameters and pass it across as a `datetime`. You only have formatting issues when you deal with this data as *strings*.

Comment: When you say you're sending the date to the db what are you sending it from? C#? As a string or a DateTime? What culture is your db set to? US/UK? If (and I don't know why you would) you do need to send it as a string try using ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, It was formed by ASP application. If i need to modify it from application, i need to make change in many places in the code. However the same code was working with the database stored in other machine. I guess there is some default DB settings that accepts only US format. How can we make the database to accept only UK based format?

Comment: @Billa you should be using DateTime parameters not strings for exactly this reason. However if you can't change your code then you'll need to change the SQL culture to UK - I THINK you need to do this on install, I don't think it can be edited afterwards

Comment: I strongly recommend to start using iso dates like YYYYMMDD when sending dates to a DB. This way it will be locale-setting agnostic and save you a whole lot of problems in the future like these.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the language to british english:

```
SET LANGUAGE 'british english'
```

or set the date format to dd/mm/yyyy

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

have a look at this too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: That only affects the date formatting options for the connection in which it is executed. Your wording may suggest to the OP that this is a permanent change to the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your default format of date in sql server by using following query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
```

Comment: That only affects the date formatting options for the connection in which it is executed. Your wording may suggest to the OP that this is a permanent change to the entire database. Also, they want `dmy` format rather than `mdy` format (and rather than doing the right thing and fixing their calling code to use parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You could use good ol' fashioned string manipulation to swap around the month and day:

```
declare @DATE_INPUT varchar(19); set @DATE_INPUT = '28/07/2014 10:53:46'

declare @US_DATE varchar(19)
set @US_DATE = SUBSTRING(@DATE_INPUT,4,2) + '/' + LEFT(@DATE_INPUT, 2) + RIGHT(@DATE_INPUT, 14)

INSERT INTO user_Log(Id,IP,DateTime)
VALUES(6, '127.0.0.1', @US_DATE);
```